# What's the purpose of depiction of visual flight track on some Jeppesen approach charts?

Tags: approach, instrument-procedures, iap

[image]

29 is the visual flight track in this chart. Why is it depicted from the MAP to the threshold of the runway? Does it signify some alternative procedures pilots are expected to perform if they decide not to perform a missed approach at the MAP?

Comment: What is the image source?

Comment: @Ron Beyer I googled it but you can find it from the chart legend in the Jeppesen Airway Manual

Comment: Looks like it's a non-precision approach (since it shows MDA) so I think you can stay at that altitude until you see the runway. It's not like a DA where you go missed if you can't see it right away. I could be wrong,though

Comment: @TomMcW Thank you for your answer but that can't be true. If you don't have the runway in sight after you have reached the MDA, you should initiate the missed approach at the missed approach point, which is depicted as "M" on the chart. You simply cannot stay at the MDA once you go past the MAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Jeppesen chart legend PDF](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/business/ifr-paper-services/intro-USA.pdf):

> Visual flight track is shown when the missed approach point is prior to the runway threshold.

So this depiction is when the MAP is before (and not at) the threshold.

[image]

### FAA style:

[image]
([airnav](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KTVL))

It's quite hard finding an early MAP, but here it is above as depicted by the FAA. It means to expect a visual segment as shown above when/if continuation below the visual descent point is not approved.

I also found this very nice read: [Where To Start The Missed Approach](http://www.terps.com/ifrr/jul95.pdf)

Comment: This definitely answers *what* it is, but the question seems to be more about *why* it's there, i.e. how does it help the pilot?

Comment: True. My question was more about the purpose of the track than about what it is. But after reading your answer, I gave my question another thought and I guess I've found an answer to it. If the visual track is depicted whenever the MAP and the threshold do not match, I guess it's to remind the pilots that they have to fly visual from the MAP to the threshold if they've decided to land. The meaning would have been clearer if the visual track was directed down to the threshold, but I guess it's depicted the way it is to prevent pilots from mistaking the MAP as a VDP. Thank you

Comment: Let me know if you have a different idea

Comment: @lemonincider - that's what I had in mind, I'll find an FAA chart to compare, it's quite likely a different way of depicting the same information but in a clear manner like you said.

Comment: @Pondlife check now